# Execute big scripts with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, upload

I made a very big script to feel my initial datas into my rails app. I have about 3000 lines in my CSV and 10000 images.

After maybe 300 upload i got this message :

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/agnostics.rb:7:in ``': Cannot allocate memory - identify -format %wx%h '/tmp/stream20111104-14788-1hsumv7.jpg[0]' (Errno::ENOMEM)
```

My upload script :

```
if (row[28] != nil)
   hotelalbum = HotelAlbumPhoto.find_or_create_by_title(h.title)
   hotelalbum.description = "Album photo de l'hotel " + h.title.capitalize
   hotelalbum.hotel_id = h.id
   hotelalbum.save

   files =  Dir.glob('IMAGES/' + row[28].gsub(/\\/,'/') + '/*.jpg')
   i =0
   for file in files
      i += 1
      photopath = File.expand_path('../../import', __FILE__) + '/' + file
      photoname = file.split('/').last
      if (i==1)
        hotelalbum.thumbnail = open(photopath)
        hotelalbum.save
      end
      if (i==1)
        h.thumbnail = open(photopath)
      end
      photo = HotelImage.find_or_create_by_image_file_name_and_hotel_album_photo_id(photoname,hotelalbum.id)
      if (photo.image_file_size == nil || photo.image_file_name != photoname)
          photo.image = open(photopath)
          photo.activated = true
          photo.alt = "Photo de l'hotel " + h.title
          photo.save
      else
         puts photopath + ' already updated'
      end
   end
end
```

When i check my memory with top command, i see ruby process use more memory on each upload. How can i manage this?

Thank you for help

ps : My server is a virtual machine with 512Mb memory, one solution is to inscrease this memory but i hope to find an other.

Comment: Are you using an attachment manager like [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)?

Comment: As another point of diagnostics, if you disable the image component does it still have memory trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where the open function is defined, but I'm suspicious that I don't see a corresponding close...

*update*  Better idea, change `photo.image = open(photopath)` to `photo.image = File.read(photopath)`

According to the docs, read:

```
Opens the file, optionally seeks to the given offset, then 
returns length bytes (defaulting to the rest of the file). 
read ensures the file is closed before returning.
```

Comment: It seems not necessary to close...but you are right, it's strange.

Comment: without closing, it's possible that a filehandle is remaining in memory, along with the file contents...

Comment: Do you know how can i close? Thank you

Comment: I don't even know what open you are calling.   Usually it is on a class, such as File.open or such.   Where is your open function defined?

Comment: I don't know, i just call open in my script. It should be the default open function of rails :)

Comment: try: after `photo.save`, add a `photo.image.close`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a memory leak problem of ImageMagick? Maybe it will help to process the list in big blocks or chunks with `in_groups_of` and force garbage collection with `GC.start` after each chunk:

```
files.in_groups_of(100) {|chunk| 
   # process chunk
   GC.start
}
```